# customer feedback through amazon mws api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using the Amazon MWS api, i want to get the negative feedback and claims from the customer. I also try the amazon product api but it gives the iframe but i need the negative feedback count or message.If anyone knows please share there answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch a report on your neutral and negative Amazon feedback (up to 3 stars) using the Amazon MWS Reports API: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html

This is an asynchronous process - first, you request a report using the `RequestReport` operation (set the `ReportType` parameter equal to `_GET_SELLER_FEEDBACK_DATA_`). After a period of time, you can call the `GetReportRequestList` operation and it will provide you with the report ID.

Using the report ID, you can finally retrieve the feedback report using the `GetReport` operation.

An easy way to test this is using the Amazon MWS Scratchpad: https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: Thanks for comment dear i have already try it but it gives a report and i want to order defect rate same as the channel advisor that is in percentage of total selling product to negative feedback, a-z claim and cash back..... and i also want to get the % in Buy Box same as the channel advisor....
If you know any solution please help me i am in a big trouble....